# How can you find out solution for linear differential equation with 2 variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have an equation

$$\frac{1}{r}g'(r)+g"(r)=0$$

where $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I was trying to solve it by substitution

Let $S=g'$, then

$$\frac{1}{r}S+S'=0$$

and

$$\frac{S'}{S}=\frac{-1}{r}$$

but it does not make any sense when integrating both parts, because $r$ is composite of two varaibles.

Comment: For the purpose of solving this ODE, you can forget where $r$ came from. You have the ODE with $r$, solve it. Then you may want to go back and use the solution by plugging $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ into it.

Comment: That does not give me a correct answer though

Comment: ?? I don't think so

Comment: Okay, I misread the equation. So, what answer are you getting and how do you know it's not correct?

Comment: Solving that equation, I got exp(c)logr+c, where c is constant. But my answer sheet says alogr^2 + b ,where a ,b are constants

Answer (score 1):

Integrating both sides of 
$$\frac{S'}{S}=\frac{-1}{r}$$
yields 
$$\log |S| = -\log r + C$$
which can be simplified to 
$$S = \frac{A}{r}$$
where $A$ is a constant that takes the place of $\pm e^C$.

Integrate once more to get $g(r) = A\log r+B$.

But note that the same answer could be expressed as $g(r) = A\log r^2+B$; the square inside the logarithm only contributes to $A$, which is an indefinite constant anyway.

In terms of $x,y$ the second form is preferable, because it's simpler: $A\log(x^2+y^2)+B$  instead of  $A\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+B$.